# How to get unit test Code Coverage using terminal + Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, code-coverage, xcode9

I have create simple demo project for getting code coverage whine I run in Xcode I am getting this coverage. look in to image

[image]

But when I run from command using terminal I can't show code coverage

```
xcodebuild -scheme Mock -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=11.1' -enableCodeCoverage YES -derivedDataPath . clean build test
```

After create report I am using this

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile=/Users/nikhil.makwana/Downloads/Mock/Build/ProfileData/70053ED1-6A92-49BB-B445-A16CF615C615/Coverage.profdata  /Users/nikhil.makwana/Downloads/Mock/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mock.app   >  jikstest.report
```

where is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This questioned was asked a long time ago. But I ran into this issue and found that you need to point to the actual file `Mock` inside the folder `Mock.app`. Here is the answer:

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile=/Users/nikhil.makwana/Downloads/Mock/Build/ProfileData/70053ED1-6A92-49BB-B445-A16CF615C615/Coverage.profdata  /Users/nikhil.makwana/Downloads/Mock/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mock.app/Mock   >  jikstest.report
```